# Modify WordPress widgets Screen

Tags: widgets

I have been searching for some time on how to modify the Widgets Administration Screen, i'm attempting to add the sidebar id to the wrapper elements.

- **Current output:** (produced by wordpress)

  ```
  <div class="widgets-holder-wrap">
  ```
- **Desired output:**

  ```
  <div id="sidebar-id-here" class="widgets-holder-wrap">
  ```

In researching i've come across [Stephanie Leary's blog](http://wpcandy.com/reports/stephanie-leary-shares-custom-redesign-of-widgets-screen) referencing the [following ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18334).

I would like do the same(add sidebar ids to their respective wrappers) but from the **theme functions.php**, ie. without modifying **wp-admin/widgets.php**.

If anyone know how it would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally suggest an enqueue, it's preferable where possible to make use of caching and script compression.

Firstly, the enqueue.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_sidebar_ids_to_widget_admin' );

function add_sidebar_ids_to_widget_admin( $current_page_hook ) {
    if( 'widgets.php' != $current_page_hook )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'widget-admin-jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/widget-admin-jquery.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}
```

I placed the code in a child theme's functions file, if you're using it elsewhere you would need to replace `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` with something else.

For

- **Child themes**

  - Use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/yourfile.js'`
- **Parent themes**

  - Use `get_template_directory_uri()  . '/yourfile.js'`
- **Plugins**

  - Use `plugins_url( '/yourfile.js', __FILE__ )`

Then some jQuery and JS to add the appropriate IDs to the holders.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#widgets-right .widgets-holder-wrap').each(function(){
        var slug = $(this).find('h3');
        $(this).attr('id', slug.text().toLowerCase().replace( /\s/g, '-' ) + 'holder-wrap' );
    });
});
```

Does pretty much exactly the same as Bainternet's solution, just approached slightly differently.

Answer (score 2):

Just Like Rarst pointed out you can't do that without either hacking core files or using JavaScript, so here is how you can do that using jQuery with a bit of pain old JavaScript string manipulation :

```
function add_sidebar_holder_id(){ 
    global $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow == 'widgets.php'){
        ?>
        <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('div[class^="widgets-holder-wrap"]').each(function()
            {       
                var SidebarNameH3 = jQuery(this).find('h3').html();
                var RemoveSpan = SidebarNameH3.indexOf("<span>");
                var SidebarName = SidebarNameH3.substring(0,RemoveSpan -1);
                SidebarName = SidebarName.replace(/ /gi,'-');
                var SidebarID = SidebarName +'-holder-wrap';
                jQuery(this).attr('id', SidebarID);
            });
        });
        </script>

        <?php
    }
}

add_action('admin_footer','add_sidebar_holder_id');
```

and you get this:

[image]

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the whole point of that ticket is that this is not possible without modifying core files (which is a bad idea as usual).

So you can either wait for that proposal to get implemented in core (if ever) or look for alternative solutions. I think some JS could help there, but not my area of expertise.